How to update metadata of a running instance in Consul?
I have a Spring Boot application that implements leader election using Consul. I need to track information about running instances of the application registered with Consul and then use it to determine the current leader.
I'm trying to implement this by changing the metadata. I use spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery and kinguinltdhk/leadership-consul libraries.
To do this, I registered the spring.cloud.consul.discovery.metadata.leader=false property in application.properties.
Next, in the following method, I get metadata by instanceId and change the value of leader to true using the put method.
public void setInstanceAsLeader(String instanceId) {
        ServiceInstance instance = discoveryClient.getInstances(appName).stream()
                .filter(i -> i.getInstanceId().equals(instanceId))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Instance not found: " + instanceId));

        if (instance instanceof ConsulServiceInstance consulInstance) {
            Map<String, String> metadata = consulInstance.getMetadata();
            if (metadata.containsKey("leader") && !metadata.get("leader").equals("true")) {
                metadata.put("leader", "true");
                System.out.println("Updated metadata: " + metadata);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Instance " + instanceId + " is leader");
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Instance is not a ConsulServiceInstance: " + instanceId);
        }
    }

However, this doesn't change the information in the Consul registry.
In response to the request http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/services I always get the following json (with "leader": "false"):
{
    "LeaderWithConsul-78db9186ba2ae11e1ef03dd0eb04b7e5": {
        "ID": "LeaderWithConsul-78db9186ba2ae11e1ef03dd0eb04b7e5",
        "Service": "LeaderWithConsul",
        "Tags": [],
        "Meta": {
            "leader": "false",
            "secure": "false"
        },
        "Port": 41851,
        "Address": "172.19.0.1",
        "TaggedAddresses": {
            "lan_ipv4": {
                "Address": "172.19.0.1",
                "Port": 41851
            },
            "wan_ipv4": {
                "Address": "172.19.0.1",
                "Port": 41851
            }
        },
        "Weights": {
            "Passing": 1,
            "Warning": 1
        },
        "EnableTagOverride": false
    }
}

Is there any way I can update metadata of a running instance in Consul?
